# My Android app source code and xml convert in to null words

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My Android app all source code and xml convert in to null words. how i back my xml and java code?

Comment: CTRL + Z, retyping it if you don't save it :) you must be more precise why it convert to null what did you do ?

Comment: when i open my project in eclipse my code and xml file are empty but file show the size.

Comment: do u know how 2 get my code and xml file?

Comment: Do you save it correctly ?? Can you open it with Notepad or Notepad++ maybe it's an encoding problem

Comment: yes i save it.. when i open it code show like this...  NULNULNUL....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Right click on the file in Package/Project Explorer and choose `Replace With > Local History..`

You can also try Right click on the Project and select `Restore from Local History` but this only restores files which have been deleted.

(Source: [my java code disappears from java file eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981405/my-java-code-disappears-from-java-file-eclipse))