# my java code disappears from java file eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am working on android project. since i was editing specific java file my laptop shutdown unexpectedly. when i switch on my laptop and open eclipse the file in which i was working show empty. there is no code :(
what should i do now ??
please help :(

for example i write this code but now its empty after computer unexpectedly shutdown

```
    public class ResourcesManager{
private BaseScene splashScene;
private BaseScene menuScene;
private BaseScene gameScene;
private BaseScene loadingScene;}
```

[image: this is the image of my file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file in Package/Project Explorer and choose `Replace With > Local History..`

You can also try Right click on the Project and select `Restore from Local History` but this only restores files which have been deleted.

Comment: It is worth using a source control system like SVN or Git just for the extra backup they provide.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the file, choose *Restore from Local History*. That is the only option as far as i know. Give it a try.

As @greg-449 said - `Replace With > Local History..` is the perfect option

Comment: Glad anyway, you were able to get it with `Replace with Local history` :)